# React code is not inserted into HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And this React code:

```
React.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

My issue is that the React statement has no effect. I thought this was because of some dependency issues in my project.

Now however, I created a fiddle and selected `LOAD TYPE: onDomReady` but still the React statement has no effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ejrce74/

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

It's `ReactDOM.render()` not `React.render()`.

See the [top level API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render).

Comment: Assuming a sufficiently recent version of React, of course. Also assuming that the code has actually been run through a compile (transpilation) step.

Comment: It has the same effect(you can see if you look at the fiddle).

Comment: @octavian I could not make React work on JSFiddle. Here's a working example on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/cifemutazi/1/edit?html,js,output . Hope it helps.